# How is it possible to post an empty answer?

Tags: bug

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205980/1699210) seems to be complete empty:

[image]

Is this a bug, or did somebody find a way to circumvent the character limit.

Comment: Maybe they used whitespace, or other "invisible" Unicode characters? What do you see when you look at the source (when you select  "edit")?

Comment: @S.L.Barth https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiIwP.png

Comment: System can always be gamed, but not without consequences. As you can see, the user who did it had their account deleted.